# Crystal Report xml file generation

Tags: xml, xslt, crystal-reports

I need to create an export in XML file with Crystal Report. 
I have an old ERP that cannot extract XML files. My need is to generate an Invoice in a XML format, following a given schema. And insert the invoices data inside that schema. There's a way to make this with Crystal Report? So when I generate the document I see the XML code inside, and then I can export it in a txt format and rename it in xml for example? My ERP use the .rpt extension modules to generate documents

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Crystal gives you full flexibility to construct the content to conform the the XML layout you need to create. What seems to be the problem?
Keep in mind that you can place static content in Report Header and Report footer to start and close the content.
Also, you can mix static and dynamic content using formula logic.

Comment: My problem is creating the xml output. If I create the rpt module, to use it with my erp, I can export from my erp, in a txt file but not xml. I don't know if can be an Erp problem or I can create an module file to export in xml directly.

Answer (score 0):

XML is just a text file. Nothing stops you from naming a TEXT export with .xml extension.